# Tableau and R Server for Python

Tags: python, r, tableau-api

I have recently discovered you can use R within Tableau, to return bool, int, long etc. This happens by the following:

```
install.packages("Rserve")
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
// Should say "Starting RServe..."
```

Then in Tableau:

```
// For Tableau under 'Help' > 'Settings and Performance' > 'Manage R Connections'
// Server: 127.0.0.1 and Port:6311
// Make sure that 'RStudio' with 'RServer' is installed and running prior to Tableau connection
```

However I would like to do the same thing with Python, so Python can be used as a script in Tableau (not using Tableau's api in Python) - anyone know if this is possible? The snippet above was taken from [here](http://www.williamqliu.com/2013/12/tableau-connection-with-r.html)

Comment: You mean use R with Python or Tableau with Python? R with python you can use pyRserve (or learn pandas, that do most of basic stuff R does). Tableau with python, I don't think there's an API for that

Comment: @Inox I mean use Python and Tableau. There's an API for tableau to use it in Python. BUT there does not seem to be a way where you can serve Python and call from Tableau as a script

Comment: There's an API to create TDEs using python (could barely call it an API but okay). What I meant is that there's no API to call python from Tableau nor vice-versa. So I guess the answer is no, its not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a Script() call for languages other than R as of Tableau 8.2.

You could try using R as a middleman to invoke Python functions via the rPython or RSPython packages. No idea how performant it would be, but might be worth the hassle if you have a significant Python library that isn't available in R.

Answer (score 1):

As of Tableau-10.1, there is a new package/library introduced which is TabPy which will act similar to Rserver for 'R' integration with Tableau.

Worth checking this article : https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/1/building-advanced-analytics-applications-tabpy-64916